# This module keeps timing out?

Tags: recursion, elixir

```
defmodule Maps do

def map([],[]) do [] end
def map([x|xs], [x1 | xs1])

 do  map([xs],[xs1]) ++ [(x + x1) | []]   end
end
```

I don't get what's wrong with it. Suppose you run `Maps.map([1],[2])`. It should then do `map(xs,xs1)` and since `xs = []` and `xs1 = []` is empty, `map ([],[])` should return `[]`, which ends the recursion. Then
`[] ++ [1+2] = [3]` so the result should return `[3]`. However, this just freezes my terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xs` and `xs1` are already lists in the second clause, but you're wrapping it in another list, which is creating infinite recursion. Changing:

```
map([xs],[xs1]) ++ [(x + x1) | []]
```

to:

```
map(xs, xs1) ++ [(x + x1) | []]
```

Gives the expected output:

```
iex(1)> Maps.map([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
[9, 7, 5]
```

Sidenote: `[x | []]` is the same as `[x]`, so you could rewrite that to just:

```
map(xs, xs1) ++ [x + x1]
```